# Python equivalent for Java parenthesis explicit typecast

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a situation with parallel inheritance like so:

```py
class FruitColor:
    # general colors
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, color:FruitColor):
        self.color:FruitColor = color

class CitrusColor(Color):
    # specialized colors
    def __init__(self, name):
        super.__init__(name)
    
    def be_citrus(self):
        print('i am a citrus color')

class CitrusFruit(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, color:CitrusColor):
        super().__init__(color)
```

Later in my program, I do something like this:

```py
orange:CitrusFruit = CitrusFruit(CitrusColor('bloodorange'))

orange.color.be_citrus()
```

I believe this should execute fine, as `orange.color` is a `CitrusColor` instance, though I’ve type hinted that it’s a `FruitColor` in the superconstructor.

However, my IDE complains that `be_citrus` is not a member of `FruitColor`. Is there a way to explicitly typecast to the subclass, as I’d do in Java?

```java
((CitrusColor) orange.color).be_citrus()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast):

```
from typing import cast

cast(CitrusColor, orange.color).be_citrus()
```

A note to people reading this, this of course does *nothing at runtime*, this simply tells any third-party tools like `mypy` that for the purposes of static type-checking the result of `orange.color` can be considered a `CitrusColor` (which **it already is at runtime**).

Your program will run *in the exact same way* with or without it.

Comment: It does *something* at runtime, but nothing useful - it just wastes a bunch of function call overhead calling a no-op function. There's no conversion or validation.

Comment: Ok yes, it is an actual function call, but it simply returns the second argument